# Get respond from application

Tags: python, linux, bash, freebsd

I have compiled application which accepts connection on port 1111.
I don't have a source code for this application, only compiled file. 
Is it possible by using simple bash/Python script to send there some portion of text for example. I tried to use nc for sending portion of text by running:
 `echo "test" | nc 127.0.0.1 1111` but I don't know how to get the respond/or be sure that application accepted this portion of text. I want to get something like "Confirm, your message "test" was received." Could you please advice? 
Application is being run on FreeBSD OS.

Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify what type of application you are trying to test. An application is not obliged to answer anything in response to arbitrary commands such as "test".

Comment: If you simply say `nc 127.0.0.1 1111`, your (terminal) stdin will go to port 1111, and whatever it sends back will go to your (terminal) stdout. If you know what this application is expecting to hear, and if its protocol is text rather than binary (ugh), you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was in specifying localhost address.

Once I specified public IP, acknowledgement was received.

Sorry everybody for wasting your time and thanks for help!